# Type mismatch on action on ngrx effect

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I created an actions file with these 3 actions:

```
export const showLoading = createAction(`[application] Show warning notification`);
export const hideLoading = createAction(`[application] Show error notification`);
export const showHttpResponseError = createAction(`[application] Show success notification`, props<{ error: HttpErrorResponse, nextAction: Action }>());

export type Actions = ReturnType<
typeof showLoading |
typeof hideLoading |
typeof showHttpResponseError
>;
```

Then I created an effects file like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class ApplicationEffects
{
    constructor(private actions$: Actions, private dialogsService: DialogsService, public notificationsService: NotificationService, private router: Router) { }

    @Effect() public erroHandler$ = this.actions$
        .pipe(
            ofType(ApplicationActions.showHttpResponseError.type),
            switchMap(action => {
                    const emptyAction = { type: 'noop' };
                    const error = HttpErrorHandler.handle(action.error);

                    if (error.redirectTo != null) {
                        this.router.navigate([error.redirectTo]);
                        return of(emptyAction);
                    }

                    if (action.error.status === 400) {
                        this.notificationsService.notifyWarning('AVISO', error.messages);
                    }
                    else {
                        this.dialogsService.errorDialog('ERRO', error.messages[0]);
                    }

                    return action.nextAction ? of(action.nextAction) : of(emptyAction);
                },
            ));
}
```

But for some reason, the VS Code intellisense is not recognizing the action type in the `switchMap`, it says it's of type `never`:

[image]

Am I missing something? Or how could I enforce the type of it, since the action is created using ngrx action creators I don't have an explicity type for it.

Comment: I usually use ofType like this: `ofType<MyAction>(MyActions.MY_ACTION)`. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, this is the old way, when you define the action class yourself, and this works. But I'm switching to the new action creators, then you don't actually have the type of the action to enforce it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For completeness, there are multiple ways:

1) type of the `ofType` operator

```
ofType<AddAction>(CounterActions.AddAction)
```

2) type the injected actions, like you already answered (starting from NgRx 7)

```
constructor(private actions$: Actions<CounterActions.Actions>
```

3) use `createEffect` in combination with `createAction` (starting from NgRx 8)

```
foo$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(addAction),
    ...
);
```

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, if someone gets the same problem, the solution is to type the injected `actions$` variable:

`private actions$: Actions<ApplicationActions.Actions>`

Then the intellisense works and you don't need to enforce an type in the `switchMap`